# Launcher disappears during normal use

Tags: 18.04, launcher

During normal system use, my sidebar/launcher occasionally disappears, and never comes back, until a restart/logoff.

I do a lot of window switching using `CTRL + ALT + ARROW`, which might be what's confusing it? I also lock my screen fairly regularly, using `SYSTEM + L`. I've never noticed the exact moment it disappears

It even **leaves a gap** on the left side of my screen where it once was:

[image: Gap from missing launcher/sidebar]

The gap is no longer registered as reserved space if I maximize new windows, or if I move them with `SYSTEM + LEFT`.

I've not installed anything custom on my machine (I have the default desktop, etc), and have a single 4k screen.

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu:GNOME

lsb_release -a
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: when it disappears.. alt f2 and then r and enter, does the dock appears?

Comment: Yes - that makes it re-appear. Thanks! Though I'm curious as to why it disappears in the first place? I don't want to do that every few hours

Comment: hey i didt tell that as a solution or answer.. just asked if restsrting gnome-shell works or not.. have you installed any gnome-shell extensions?

Comment: can you also attach a pic when launcher exists

Comment: When your system is locked, it may go in sleep modus. That might break the Dock: sleep modus does not always work flawlessly. You can test whether that is the cause by preventing the computer to sleep when you lock (Settings - Privacy). Not a solution again, but might narrow down on the cause of the issue. Better also post some system specs, in particular the graphics card. It that is the issue, you will probably not find a solution - as a workaround, you can then avoid sleep modus permanently.